# split string to Dictionnary<string, int>

Tags: c#, dictionary, split

I have a string like that : "content;123 contents;456 contentss;789 " etc..

I would like to split this string to get a Dictionary, but I don't know you to make it. I try to split the string but I got a List only.

The content (before semi colon) is always a unique string.
After the semi colon, I always have a number until I found the space.
the number is always an int (no float needs).

Could someone help me please ?

Comment: _"content is always a unique string"_ - but could it contain a space?

Comment: If you split the string into a List then you are 75% of the way there.  Next you need to add the list items into the Dictionary.

Comment: Why the downvotes? The user clearly stated the problem.

Comment: @Kjata30: Because the poster is just asking for the community to write their code.  It sounds like they called .Split(), saw it gave a List, and gave up.  In retrospect, I should have originally replied with "What have you tried so far?"  I will do that next time.

Comment: I didn't know about split inside a Select to combine double split and get my elements for the ToDictionnary call. It seems that everybody should be born in the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following LINQ expression:

```
"content;123 contents;456 contentss;789"
    .Split(' ')
    .Select(x => x.Split(';'))
    .ToDictionary(x => x[0], x => int.Parse(x[1]));
```

Comment: Assuming 'contents' never contains a space.

Comment: @HenkHolterman, right! Otherwise, I'll prefer EZI's solution with regexes.

Answer (score 2):

```
string input = "content1;123 content2;456 content3;789";
var dict = Regex.Matches(input, @"(.+?);(\d+)").Cast<Match>()
                .ToDictionary(m => m.Groups[1].Value, m => int.Parse(m.Groups[2].Value));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var myList = "content1;number1 content2;number2 content3;number3";
var myDictionary = myList.Split(' ').Select(pair => pair.Split(';')).ToDictionary(splitPair => splitPair[0], splitPair => int.Parse(splitPair[1]));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
string value = "content;123 contents;456 contentss;789";
Dictionary<string, int> data = new Dictionary<string,int>();

foreach(string line in value.Split(' '))
{
    string[] values = line.Split(';');
    if (!data.ContainsKey(values[0]))
    {
        data.Add(values[0], Convert.ToInt32(values[1]));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string content = "content;123 contents;456 contentss;789";
        Dictionary<string, int> result = new Dictionary<string, int>();

        content.Split(' ').ToList().ForEach(x =>
        {
            var items = x.Split(';');
            result.Add(items[0], int.Parse(items[1]));
        });

        foreach(var item in result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} -> {1}" , item.Key, item.Value);
        }
    }
```